# How to name questions about closed questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, title

I just posted a question on English and Usage meta asking about why a question was closed, but because I couldn't come up with a better title, the first one I tried was "Why was this question closed?"

In the "Questions that may already have your answer" list under the question title appeared a long list of similarly named questions differing only by a letter or a synonymous word. This is kind of a real problem. I think SE should have some hint popping up when it detects a "Why was this question closed" kind of title and help the user come up with a better one.

But right now the site just won't let those questions through saying a question with the same title already exists. And this I think is a bug, since it doesn't really offer any help in improving the question title.

I don't really think simply allowing questions with the same titles to be posted is the right way to solve this problem. Question titles should be descriptive, but in a case like this, I think it's better to have a whole separate feature that will allow to post a question about deleted questions for meta sites. I guess an ok start could be placing a marker `why was this question closed` and the full title of the closed question *in question* as the title.

Comment: It really isn't a bug. You could at most make it a feature-request if you think that on Meta questions with the exact same title should be allowed.

Comment: Why do we need "a whole separate feature"? What's wrong with the existing feature?

Comment: @CodyGray I'm talking about a way to mark questions about closed questions, so that the users won't have to come up with a title that in such case wouldn't provide much additional information about the question. Since the title of the question describes the essence of it, surely then such questions would have the same titles. Why not omit coming up with the title then?

Comment: Because questions need a title to differentiate them from other questions. I can't believe I had to say that. We do, however, have some tags to "mark" this type of question: [meta-tag:specific-question] and [meta-tag:reopen-closed].

Comment: @CodyGray that's why I'm proposing to simply automatically copy the original question title into the meta question about it being closed, only adding a marker that this meta question is about that non-meta question (which already has its own unique title) being closed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you'll have to try a little harder. Add some more words to the title that actually *describe* or *summarize* the question to which you refer.

For example:

> Why was this question about creating multiple threads in C# closed?

> Why was this ASP.NET MVC 4 server configuration question closed?

> Can we re-open this question about sorting a list of integers in Python?

If you can't figure out a way to summarize the question in a meta title, it probably isn't ready to be reopened yet. Keep editing until you get a focused core question to emerge.

Comment: Exactly. I was going to list the same patterns.

Comment: I don't think infusing the title of the original into the title of the meta question about it is the right way to ask a question on such topic.

Comment: @user1306322 Why not? Adding more information to the title certainly doesn't seem like it would hurt.

Comment: @Asad How much more information can you add to better describe the question about closed question? I guess it's the whole original title. An example would be "Why was the question about <insert original question title here> closed?" but that doesn't really look alright. And sometimes you just can't add a part of the original title so that it would still make sense.

Comment: No, you definitely do not want the whole title of the original question, because that describes a different question. You are asking a Meta question about re-opening that question. It should be titled rather differently.

Comment: *"And sometimes you just can't add a part of the original title so that it would still make sense."* Err, challenge accepted? Do beware that I already addressed this in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @user1306322 Look at it this way, your question is (hopefully) distinct from all the other meta-posts about closed questions that should be re-opened. What makes it unique is the details specific to the situation you're describing, so you should try to briefly mention these details in your title. Eg. "Why was this question about <on topic subject matter> closed as off topic?"

Comment: @CodyGray my original question was called `“Introduce person to object” or “introduce object to person”`, and if you can come up with a sensible title for my meta post (challenge offered), I will gladly change my meta question title to that.

Comment: My original question was "Colorless pink furry animals without hair", how should I title a Meta question about it? Yeah, you're going to need to link to the actual question in order for me to answer that. Aside from that lack of context, that doesn't sound like a very good question title in the first place. Perhaps you should start by focusing on *that* title?

Comment: @CodyGray oh, [I can do that to you too](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%E2%80%9CIntroduce+person+to+object%E2%80%9D+or+%E2%80%9Cintroduce+object+to+person%E2%80%9D). There is no need for that sarcasm and doubting every move of your users, presuming they're doing everything wrong.